# Reference where a python script is located if being run from another location

Tags: python, working-directory

I'm trying to run a python script from a different location than where it is located but I need to reference files where the python script is located. I tried the following:

```
os.chdir(os.getcwd())
```

But unfortunately that gets the current working dir of where I ran the script from, not where the script currently lives.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

to get the directory your script is located in.

Comment: Indeed, `__file__` contains the path of the current file, so the code in this answer will give you the directory in which the file resides.

Comment: NameError: name file is not defined.

Comment: @kame: In the interactive interpreter, `__file__` is undefined.